# How could I change this piece of code so that I only have getKey?

Tags: java

```
private void searchForK(V value , DictionaryNode<K,V> node){
        if(node != null){
            if(((Comparable<V>)value).compareTo(node.value) == 0) {
                obtainKey = node.key;
                return;
            }
            searchForK(value,node.lChild); //recursive since we have to simply look
            searchForK(value,node.rChild);//through each child which is itself another searchforK
        }       
    }

public K getKey(V value) {
    searchForK(value,rNode);
    return obtainKey;

}//end getKey
```

How do I change the above code into just a function of getKey? I'm confused with the recursion. I want to get rid of the function searchForK, and have getKey have the same function as searchForK.

Here is my attempt in changing the two functions:

```
public K getKey(V value) {
        //  private void searchForK(V value , DictionaryNode<K,V> node){
        if(rNode != null){
            if(((Comparable<V>)value).compareTo(rNode.value) == 0) {
                obtainKey = rNode.key;
                return (K) obtainKey;
            }
                rNode = rNode.lChild;
                getKey(value);
                rNode = rNode.rChild;
                getKey(value);
            }   
        return null;
```

It doesn't behave the same way though, what am I doing wrong?

These are my global variables:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<K,V> implements DictionaryADT<K,V> {
    /* data fields */

    /* Node Variables */
    public DictionaryNode<K,V> rNode; //Root Node
    public DictionaryNode<K,V> pNode; //Parent Node
    K obtainKey;
```

Should I replace that curNode with rNode in my case?

Comment: I'm still a newbie when it comes to recursion. This is kinda difficult for me.

Comment: You will have to use two references to keep track of where you are currently recursing as you can't pass the reference to the node with each recursive call. What type of data structure are you searching?

Comment: I'm searching a Binary Search Tree. It's killing me man. The recursion is. Thanks for helping me out. I have another part where I need help. Can you stay with me? I'm a Computer Science Student, undergrad.

Comment: I assume the tree is balanced so that it can be seareched in O(log n) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private DictionaryNode<K,V> curNode = rNode;

public K getKey(V value) {

    if (curNode != null) {
         int c = ((Comparable<V>)curNode.value).compareTo(value);

         if (c == 0) {

              K key = curNode.key;

              curNode = rNode; // reset curNode
              return key;
         }
         else if (c < 0 && curNode.lChild != null) {
              curNode = curNode.lChild;
              return getKey(value);
         }
         else if (curNode.rChild != null) {
              curNode = curNode.rChild;
              return getKey(value);
         }
    }
    curNode = rNode; // reset curNode
    return null;
```

}

Comment: Why is your DictionaryNode outside of the function?

Comment: ah I see what you are doing now, one second

Comment: You do? How do you know what I'm doing?

Comment: I think that you have implemented a binary tree with a linked list and you want to do an in-order traversal of the tree returning the key of the first node that's value is equal to the value initial passed to getKey.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. : D. However I don't see where I will place that curNode variable how do I pass rNode to my function getKey? when it should only take a V value.

Comment: well if you want to implement the entire algorithm in one method you can't pass in a second argument. So you have to keep track of what node you are currently recursing over. curNode implants that. so curNode's type will be Dictionay<K,V> and its value will be the node in the linked list currently being examined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42818/discussion-between-robbmj-and-twilightsparklethegeek)